# How to call a function from the directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have this controller:

```
    .controller('UserListEditorController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.status = {
          isopenFields: false,
          isopenFilters: false
        };

        $scope.toggleDropdownFields = function($event) {
           $scope.status.isopenFields = !$scope.status.isopenFields;
        };

        $scope.toggleDropdownFilters = function($event) {
           $scope.status.isopenFilters = !$scope.status.isopenFilters;
        };
     })
```

And I have this directive:

```
.directive('myDraggable', ['$document', function($document) {
        return {
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
                    element.data('mousedown', true);
                });
                element.on('focusin', function(event) {
                    if (element.data('mousedown')) {
                        Calling $scope.toggleDropdown
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

How do I call a function that is in controllers $scope from the custom directive?

Comment: There is no need for it I guess. I just need to know what is a right way to call a function. Html can be just something simple like this: ```<div myDraggable></div>```

Comment: can't u use like `scope.toggleDropdown()` ?

Comment: @Tachi If directive is defined descendant of the controller you can use what K.Toress suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have create a directive type of `shared scope` so if you define a directive with shared scope you can directly access the properties of the `ng-controller`

just as,

```
scope.sayHello();
```

here is the [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gxLCuec1c1CRBjQikQ3g?p=preview)

may be you have gone wrong with calling `element.data..`, in angular directive you can access the attribute you put to the element as `attr.mousedown`

Here is a good [Series to Refer](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scope.toggleDropdownFields()`if your directive scope is **not isolated** and if the directive is called inside the scope of the controller `UserListEditorController`.

Please refer

Html

```
<button ng-controller="MyCtrl" dir>I just met you</button>
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.directive('dir', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                scope.click();
            });
        }
    };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.click = function () {
        console.log("Whatever you want to do");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it:

Markup:

```
<button ng-controller="SomeCtrl" my-directive call-me="callMeMaybe()">I just met you</button>
```

JS:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.directive('myDirective', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind('click', function (e) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.callMe);
                });
            }
        };
    });

    function SomeCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.callMeMaybe = function () {
            alert('I just called you, maybe');
        };
    }
```